# Get transform property of $(this) class and not computed inline property

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of circles. Some scaled 0.5, some .0.6 etc. through attached classes like: `circle size-xs`, `circle size-lg` like:

```
<div class="circle size-xs"></div>
<div class="circle size-md"></div>
<div class="circle size-lg"></div>
```

When I mouseenter a circle I scale it to 1.0 - however on mouseout, I want to return to the default scale defined in the class

```
$('.circle').on('mouseenter', function() {
    TweenMax.to($(this), 0.5, {scale: 1, ease: Power2.easeOut});
});

$('.circle').on('mouseout', function() {
    TweenMax.to($(this), 0.5, {scale: someScaleIntFromTheClass], ease: Power2.easeOut});
});
```

If I do `$(this).css("transform")` I will get the inline scale of 1 and not the scale which is defined in the class of the element anymore.

How would I go about always getting the transform scale property of the $(this) class on mouseout?

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery will only be able to read the current CSS of the element (i.e. the inline CSS set by TweenMax). You could store the original scale in a variable in your JS, or a data attribute on the element (like `data-scale`). But is there a particular reason you're using TweenMax for these animations when you could achieve them with CSS `:hover` and `transition`?

Comment: Can you show some css for classes `size-xs` etc

Comment: There's a nice CSS solution below but if you really need to do this in Jquery then try to assign a `data-scale` attribute to the elements then just retrieve the value using `$(this).data('scale');`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are looking for a jQuery solution initially - but in this setup I would lean towards a CSS solution.

Not least because when the `:hover` pseudo-class no longer applies, each div will naturally return to the default scale value you have declared for it in the stylesheet.

**Example:**

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.circle {
border-radius: 50px;
transition: transform ease-out 0.6s;
}

.size-xs {
transform: scale(0.2);
}

.size-md {
transform: scale(0.4);
}

.size-lg {
transform: scale(0.8);
}

.circle:hover {
transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle size-xs"></div>
<div class="circle size-md"></div>
<div class="circle size-lg"></div>
```